# passing argument 1 of 'print' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, pointers

First, I have to say that I just started learning pointers, so I'm kind of lost. My professor told me to make a program which reads names, ages, antiquity and docket of X quantity of people, and when it's done, print it on a table-like format. For all of that, I have to have 2 separate functions. One that reads what the user inputs, and other that outputs everything the user inputted in a table like format.

Now, the problem is that I cannot pass my 3D array to the `printt()` function. The idea is that I don't pass the whole array, instead I just pass the memory address (using &) and then I reference that memory address to all my `printf()`s (using *).

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define sfb if(db[i][0][0] == 17 || db[i][1][0] == 17 || db[i][2][0] == 17 || db[i][3][0] == 17){break;}

void read();
void printt(char *dbp);

int main(){
    read();
}

void read(){
    char db[20][3][20];
    printf("Ingrese ^Q para salir\n");
    for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
        printf("Ingrese nombre de persona: ");
        fgets(db[i][0], sizeof db[i][0], stdin);
        db[i][0][strcspn(db[i][0], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese legajo de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][1], sizeof db[i][1], stdin);
        db[i][1][strcspn(db[i][1], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese edad de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][2], sizeof db[i][2], stdin);
        db[i][2][strcspn(db[i][2], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese antiguedad de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][3], sizeof db[i][3], stdin);
        db[i][3][strcspn(db[i][3], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
    }
    printt(&db);
    }

    void printt(char *dbp){
        int i = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a <= 20; a++){
            printf("% 40c|% 20c|% 10c|% 15c\n", "Nombre", "Legajo", "Edad", "Antiguedad");
            printf("% 40c|% 20c|% 10c|% 15c\n", *dbp[a][i], *dbp[a][i+1], *dbp[a][i+2], *dbp[a][i+3]);
            i = i +4 ;
        }
    }
```

Here are all the errors I get when I try to compile (I hope that all of them are related to pointers):

```
passing argument 1 of 'printt' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types] [35,12]
format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Werror=format=] [41,25]
format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'char *' [-Werror=format=] [41,32]
format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'char *' [-Werror=format=] [41,37]
format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 5 has type 'char *' [-Werror=format=] [41,43]
subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector [42,56]
expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int" [42,57]
subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector [42,68]
expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int" [42,69]
subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector [42,82]
expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int" [42,83]
subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector [42,96]
expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int" [42,97]
```

Comment: You don't need a 3D array, not even a 2D array, you just need a flat array of structs that can group all the info for each person. You obviously need to practice your skills before you delve into 3D arrays.

Comment: One thing: `for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)` breaks the array bounds. Use `< 20`.

Comment: [The warning stack](https://godbolt.org/z/dETK7ocK8) from this code is almost as large as the code itself. The specific error you're asking about is nothing if not self-explanatory. The function being called expects `char*`. You're giving it a `char (*)[20][3][20]`. Those aren't synonymous or compatible (in even the most vivid of imaginations).

Comment: already mentioned, have you covered `struct`s yet? This is begging to be implemented using a `struct`. Doable with a multi-dimension array I suppose, but that doesn't scale well, and only allows one data type. Your problem says you need 4 different fields for X number of people, so using this approach wouldn't you need a 4 dimensional array anyway? What if you needed 20 fields? I don't even know what the cap is on the number of dimensions to an array in C, but there probably is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many said, the solution would be to simply use structs. At the time I asked this question I didnt know nothing about structs, so here is a solution for those who dont know structs and still want to use 3D arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define sfb if(db[i][0][0] == 17 || db[i][1][0] == 17 || db[i][2][0] == 17 || db[i][3][0] == 17){break;}

void read();
void printt(char *dbp);

int main(){
    read();
}

void read(){
    char db[20][4][20] = {0};
    printf("Ingrese ^Q para salir\n");
    for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
        printf("Ingrese nombre de persona: ");
        fgets(db[i][0], sizeof db[i][0], stdin);
        db[i][0][strcspn(db[i][0], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese legajo de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][1], sizeof db[i][1], stdin);
        db[i][1][strcspn(db[i][1], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese edad de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][2], sizeof db[i][2], stdin);
        db[i][2][strcspn(db[i][2], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese antiguedad de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][3], sizeof db[i][3], stdin);
        db[i][3][strcspn(db[i][3], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
    }
    printt(&db[0][0][0]);
}

void printt(char *dbp){
    printf("%-40s|%-20s|%-10s|%-15s\n", "Nombre", "Legajo", "Edad", "Antiguedad");
    for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++){
        printf("%-40s|%-20s|%-10s|%-15s\n", &dbp[a*80], &dbp[a*80+20], &dbp[a*80+40], &dbp[a*80+60]);
    }
}
```

First of all, change every "`% XXc`" for "`%-XXs`". The `-` is there so the text is formatted to the left. Using the space only makes sense for numeric values.

The "`s`" is there because we're trying to print an array of characters, also known as a string of characters. The `%s` format specifier makes the function print every character (or %c) until a NULL or "`/0`" is encountered. A `%c` will only print one character, no matter what.

Now for the hard part. First, the call to the function `read` expects a memory location. In this case, `&db` itself is kind of an incomplete pointer, because it points to the first group of four group of twenty characters. The correct way would be to give the function the address to the first character, since in the prototype a `char *` is defined. If the prototype would've had a `char *[20]` it would be one step forward for `&db` itself to be a complete pointer. Anyway, going back to the actual code, to be able to comply with what the function asks for, I have to point to the first character of the WHOLE array, it being `&db[0][0][0]`

Now, to be able to read every character, some knoweldge about how arrays are stored is needed (its not that hard). For a 3D array, the way the individual characters are stored follows this table:
[image]
I think its pretty self-explainatory. In memory, everithing is stored one after the other. So, it first stores, the twenty chars of the 1st slot of the 1st slot, and then the twenty chars of the 2nd slot of the 1st slot, and so on. What I'm trying to say, is that you can see the contents of the char array `db[0][0]`, just by inspecting the first memory addres of `db`, and the contents of `db[0][1]` are just 20 characters away from the first memory address of `db`! And thats basically it. If you want to see the contents of `db[5][2]`, you can just do `(5 * 4 * 20)+(20 * 3)`, and the result will be the distance from the memory addres of `db` to the char array you want to see. The logic behind this is that if I want to acces `db[0][0]`, `0` would be my memory address, if i want to acces `db[0][1]`, `0+20` (20 because my last dimension is 20) would be my memory addres, and if i want to access `db[1][0]`, my memory addres would be `0+(4*20)` (4 because the second dimension of my array is 4)